# Adding a third dimesion to a family of xy-plots

Tags: plotting

I imported a table from Excel in the column format of x, y1, y2, ..., y7

I used

```
ListLinePlot[Table[q[[All, {1, i}]], {i, 2, 7}], PlotRange -> range]
```

to plot each of the seven y-values against its associated x-value.

I now want to to do a 3D plot of this data against time. So I want to plot `x-y1, x-y2, ...`, with increments of time. For example, `x-y1` happened at 1 minute, `x-y2` happened at 2 minutes.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to make something like the waterfall plot in Origin?

Comment: Please show us the data and code for the plot you have have already made. It will help us to better uwnderstand your problem and increase the likelihood of your getting an answer/